# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 Cant change conky font

Tags: gnome, 16.04, fonts, conky

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Gnome DE 3.18. Then installed conky-manager to customize my desktop. Everything worked well and the only problem now I am facing is changing fonts. I dont know how to change the fonts. I even tried to change it from the conky file of each theme but it still didnt work. Can anyone help me with this thing ?